# Git renaming caused unable to switch between branches

Tags: git, renaming, ignore-case

I am confused by the following scene.Could you please help me to fix it? Here are the commands and outputs from osx terminal:

```
mkdir test && cd test && git init
```

> Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/martin/Downloads/test/.git/

```
echo "a">>a.txt
git add . && git commit -m "a"
```

> [master (root-commit) bc140ee] a
>
> 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
>
> create mode 100644 a.txt

```
git config core.ignorecase false
git checkout -b dev
```

> Switched to a new branch 'dev'

```
mv a.txt A.txt && echo "b">>A.txt
git add . && git commit -m "b"
```

> [dev 04a21d6] b
>
> 2 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
>
> create mode 100644 A.txt

```
git checkout master
```

> Switched to branch 'master'

```
git checkout dev
```

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
>
> A.txt
>
> Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
>
> Aborting

The question is how could i switch from 'master' to 'dev' without --force?

Additional information to explain:

1. My git version: 2.3.0
2. I am working on OS X 10.11.6, so it's case insensitive for git by default. But I use git to manage our java source codes, i configured git with case sensitive as the above command showing.

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `git --version` ? 2.9.0 works fine for me. `$ git checkout dev`
`Switched to branch 'dev'`

Comment: Is your filesystem case sensitive or case insensitive?

Comment: @BryceDrew I did, what has that to do with my question?

Comment: @BryceDrew I just tested it with 2.9.2. Unfortunately, the output is the same.

Comment: Why are you changing `core.ignorecase`?  You shouldn't do that on a case insensitive filesystem; this is _exactly_ the problem that setting prevents.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I converted some letters of file name from lower case to upper case, in order to fix "missing spelling warning" from IDE.Maybe i should keep `core.ignorecase` as it was? If i do so, git will not pickup my modifications when there is a file name's case conversion only. I hate to rename file name with `git mv --`!